# how to get struct data from contract by web3?

Tags: solidity, web3js, remix, javascript

I tried to get the data of the struct by its mapping string, but I got undefined in innerhtml and get following result in the html console log:

[image]

**however I can search the data from the Remix ABI**, anyone know how to retrieve the data by web3?

my web3 version is 1.5.1, and the entire code is [here](https://github.com/ginwei/carbon-account)

this is my solidity code:

```
pragma solidity >=0.7.0 <0.9.0;

contract Storage{

    string b = "calculation a";
    struct UserInfo {
        string time;
        string source;
        uint emission;
    }
    mapping (string => UserInfo) users;

    the function of saving data is ignored
    
    function search(string memory input_source) public view returns (uint, string memory) {
        return (users[input_source].emission, users[input_source].time);
    }
}
```

and this is the javascript

```
// Initialize Web3
var web3 = new Web3('http://localhost:7545');

// Set Account
web3.eth.defaultAccount = '0x16E15b184F39c4fBE1A4B29052CE018c5748610B';

// Set Contract Abi
var ABI = [abi];

// Set Contract Address
var contractAddress = 'my addr'; // Add Your Contract address here!!!

// Set the Contract
var contract = new web3.eth.Contract(ABI, contractAddress);

//get the formCarbonEmission data
function showCompanyResultLineChart() {
  const input_company = document.getElementById("company");//the "company" is the id of the button"
  const companyResultLineChart = document.getElementById("companyResultLineChart");
  //the "companyResultLineChart" is the id for displaying the data
  
  const result = contract.methods.search(input_company).call({from:web3.eth.defaultAddress});
  console.log(result)
  companyResultLineChart.innerHTML = "the " + input_company.value + 
" factory created " + result[0] + " tons of CO2 in " + result[1];//the result[] show "undefined".
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Reading from the Ethereum blockchain is asynchronous. You need to either define `showCompanyResultLineChart()` as an async function and await the read method call as in:

```js
async function showCompanyResultLineChart() {
...
  
  const result = await contract.methods.search(input_company).call({from:web3.eth.defaultAddress});
...
}
```

Or, use the `then(..)` syntax and place all result-dependent lines in the callback function as in:

```js
function showCompanyResultLineChart() {
...
  
  contract.methods.search(input_company).call({from:web3.eth.defaultAddress}).then((result) => {
  console.log(result)
  companyResultLineChart.innerHTML = "the " + input_company.value + 
" factory created " + result[0] + " tons of CO2 in " + result[1];//the result[] show "undefined".
});
}
```

Comment: thanks for your solution. But now I find out that it didn't show the result I input, it shows null. Do u have any idea of this? (I can get the result in remix)

Comment: @ginwei maybe try without the `{from:..}` part? It's not really needed for a read call.

Comment: I've tried it and still not work. I've google the solution, but none of the solution I found work for it...

Comment: I can return the data in the function I save data, but I can't do it in the `search` function. So it seems that the mapping struct can't passing through different function. That's may be the point for solution.

Comment: and i also find this: [problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52656813/function-error-with-my-solidity-mapint-string-while-using-javascript-to-return). But i still don't know how to solve it.